# How to use Restricted Data Token (RDT) in Amazon SP Api for Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, api

I am using [Amazon SP api with generated Java SDK](https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/blob/main/guides/en-US/developer-guide/SellingPartnerApiDeveloperGuide.md#connecting-to-the-selling-partner-api-using-a-generated-java-sdk). My test-application is checking the orders and also the delivery address. According to Amazon, this should be a [restricted operation](https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/blob/main/guides/en-US/use-case-guides/tokens-api-use-case-guide/tokens-API-use-case-guide-2021-03-01.md#restricted-operations). But at the moment, I can get the information without the usage of RDT. I tried to use RDT as shown below but it is not working.

```
// Build orders-api
OrdersV0Api ordersApi = new OrdersV0Api.Builder()
              .awsAuthenticationCredentials(awsAuthenticationCredentials)
              .lwaAuthorizationCredentials(lwaAuthorizationCredentials)
              .awsAuthenticationCredentialsProvider(awsAuthenticationCredentialsProvider)
              .endpoint("https://sellingpartnerapi-eu.amazon.com")
              .build();
    
List<String> orderStatuses = new ArrayList<String>();
orderStatuses.add(OrderStatusEnum.UNSHIPPED.getValue());
    
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -3);
    
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXX");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
String tmp = sdf.format(new Date());
    
try {
    // Get orders
    GetOrdersResponse respOrders = ordersApi.getOrders(Marketplaces.getAllMarketplaces(), sdf.format(cal.getTime()), null, null, null, orderStatuses, null, null, null, null, 100, null, null, null);
    OrderList orders = respOrders.getPayload().getOrders();
    Order ord = orders.get(0);
        
    // Restricted Data Token
    RestrictedResource rr = new RestrictedResource();
    rr.setMethod(MethodEnum.GET);
    rr.setPath("/orders/v0/orders/" + ord.getAmazonOrderId() + "/address");

    CreateRestrictedDataTokenRequest req = new CreateRestrictedDataTokenRequest();
    req.addRestrictedResourcesItem(rr);
    
    TokensApi tokensApi = new TokensApi.Builder()
              .awsAuthenticationCredentials(awsAuthenticationCredentials)
              .lwaAuthorizationCredentials(lwaAuthorizationCredentials)
              .awsAuthenticationCredentialsProvider(awsAuthenticationCredentialsProvider)
              .endpoint("https://sellingpartnerapi-eu.amazon.com")
              .build(); 

    CreateRestrictedDataTokenResponse resp3 = tokensApi.createRestrictedDataToken(req);
    String token = resp3.getRestrictedDataToken();

    // Add token to Header ?
    ordersApi.getApiClient().addDefaultHeader("x-amz-access-token", token); 
        
    // Get delivery adress
    GetOrderAddressResponse respAdress = ordersApi.getOrderAddress(ord.getAmazonOrderId());
    Address adr = respAdress.getPayload().getShippingAddress();
        
} catch (ApiException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When I execute this, I am getting this error:
*"message": "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.*

It seems like only setting x-amz-access-token is not the right operation to add the RDP. But I also can not see any other operation on ordersApi or ordersApi.getApiClient that seems to be the right one.
And also it is unclear to me, why it is working when I just completely not use tokens-api at all.

Comment: I remember we recently had something similar. You need to make sure your AWS IAM AccessKey/Secret are from the same region as you are making the request. So if you are calling sellingpartnerapi-eu.amazon.com then region is eu-west1. All credentials need also be eu-west1. The keyword "Credential Scope" was important in our case and this section of the documentation helped: https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/blob/main/guides/en-US/developer-guide/SellingPartnerApiDeveloperGuide.md#credential-scope

Comment: Restricted Data tokens will be required for this access around July 2022.  So, while it works now, it won't in the future.
Did you ever get the restricted resource endpoint working?  Struggling with it now.

Comment: i honestly think the API is broken... it doesn't make any sense it sends in two x-amz-access-tokens instead of just one which is causing it to break postman works fine... but these java classes not so much.

Comment: @Giga I am having a very similar issue. Could you manage to solve it with Java SDK? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

According to RDT Token Flow and Amazon SP-API Java SDK I want to point to [this official example workflow](https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-models/blob/817ca69acc83a40cfc0b02c7dda5d6534a9c752a/clients/sample-code/RestrictedDataTokenWorkflow.java).

Unfortunately the use of
`ordersApi.getApiClient().addDefaultHeader("x-amz-access-token", token);`
is broken in the ApiClient provided by Amazon and needs some custom adjustment to make it work.

If the request is only signed by LwaAuthorizationSigner when x-amz-access-token is missing, fixes the flow for me. Compare this [PR](https://github.com/loaded02/selling-partner-api-models/pull/1/files)

Change ApiClient.java like this:

```
-        request = lwaAuthorizationSigner.sign(request);
+        if (!defaultHeaderMap.containsKey("x-amz-access-token")) {
+            request = lwaAuthorizationSigner.sign(request);
+        }
```

Comment: What was the custom adjustment? Has the repo been updated by anyone?

Comment: No updates to the repo yet. I have edited my response.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately this is still an issue in the C# SDK. The code to modify is under the InterceptRequest function of the ApiClient.cs in each API, for anyone else looking. What a miserable experience this migration to SP-API has been.